# How to target elements in li with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Here is a code of javascript for example i want to change the text in the span that is nested in li. How do i use the DOM to target this elements ?

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
body.style.fontFamily = "Arial";
var name = document.getElementsById('name');
var index = document.getElementsById('index');
var hometown = document.getElementsById('hometown');
name.innerHTML = "NAME";
index.innerHTML = "INDEX";
hometown.innerHTML = "HOMETOWN";
```

```html
<h1>About Me</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Name: <span id="name"></span></li>
    <li>Index: <span id="index"></span></li>
      <li>Hometown: <span id="hometown"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @mplungjan what do you mean by "Typo. getElementById is singular" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Typo: getElementById is singular - it is getElementById and not getElementsById
- Also don't have a var with the same name as an ID in the page – it hides the var
- Also please close the `<li>` for formatting reasons

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
body.style.fontFamily = "Arial";
var nameSpan = document.getElementById('name'); // either change the var or the ID - I suggest the ID since name is used in several places like window.name etc
var index = document.getElementById('index');
var hometown = document.getElementById('hometown');
nameSpan.innerHTML = "NAME";
index.innerHTML = "INDEX";
hometown.innerHTML = "HOMETOWN";
```

```html
<h1>About Me</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Name: <span id="name"></span></li>
  <li>Index: <span id="index"></span></li>
  <li>Hometown: <span id="hometown"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firsts of all you have a typo in `getElementsById`, it should be `getElementById`.
And second, you should `+=` the HTML not just `=`, cause it deletes the text in your HTML and replace it with the value you set in JavaScript.
And the last thing, it's better to give an id for `<li>`, it's more sufficient than making span, I think.

This is te fixed HTML and JS:

```js
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML += "anything";
document.getElementById("index").innerHTML += "anything";
document.getElementById("hometown").innerHTML += "anything";
```

```html
<h1>About Me</h1>
<ul>
  <li id="name">Name:
    <li id="index">Index:
      <li id="hometown">Hometown:
</ul>
```

Comment: 1. I think we already discussed the spelling to death. 2. The spans are empty so no need to += unless you remove the spans like you did

Answer (score 0):

you have typos in the script as `getElementById` not `getElementsById`

Also HTML Have some tag issue

Try this

```
<ul>
  <li>Name: <span id="name"></span></li>
  <li>Index: <span id="index"></span></li>
  <li>Hometown: <span id="hometown"></span></li>
</ul>



    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
    body.style.fontFamily = "Arial";
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var index = document.getElementById('index');
    var hometown = document.getElementById('hometown');
    name.innerHTML = "NAME";
    index.innerHTML = "INDEX";
    hometown.innerHTML = "HOMETOWN";
```

Comment: `var name` and `name.innerHTML="NAME"` doesn't work.